# How many neutrinos would it take to kill you?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, estimation, neutrinos, biology

Of course, there are many different kinds, so let's assume:

1. they'rre all standard $v_e$.
2. they all intersect your body in random places.
3. they are going at say, 10% of c (about accelerator speed). 

   the standard target for a lethal dose is 50% of human adult subjects dead, either immediately or from complications (which is more likely with neutrinos as they have a small chance each of weak-forcing a neutron to beta decay, which can disrupt cellular function and give you cancer). How many would it take for this to happen?

Comment: 10% of c makes for some very, very, very low energy neutrinos.

Comment: Related/Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/46467/50583

Comment: We have never detected a neutrino that is so slow. They are very relativistic, always travelling at nearly c. The odds to interact with a neutrino drastically decrease for low energy (i.e. slow) neutrinos.

Comment: @JonathanJeffrey It's not very convenient to talk about velocity when things are going that fast, you'd end up with numbers like 0.9999999999999c. So instead we use the particle's kinetic energy. Another good value is the [Lorentz factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor), although that's not much use with neutrinos, since we don't have accurate values of their rest masses (and so we don't have accurate values for their speeds, either).

Comment: From https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/197595/123208 the neutrino mass is somewhere between 0.1 and 1 eV/c². Also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/267035/123208 But the best [neutrino detectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutrino_detector) can't see neutrinos with less kinetic energy than 233 keV, so those neutrinos have (at least) a quarter of a million times as much KE as rest mass-energy. And the detectors catch fewer than 1 neutrino per billion that pass through them.

Comment: Related because it made me think of this and it's part of an using answer, or speculation on a similar question. https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/

Comment: Did you try to do a back-of-an-envelope-calculation?

Comment: [Supernovae emit fatal neutrino doses if observed at 1 AU](https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/) (in addition to fatal doses of everything else).  So this question can be answered.  Although I’d throw out the ill-defined/bad $v_e$ & 0.1c assumptions & just use the average solar neutrino KE.

Answer (score 1):

> [Each second there are about 100 billion](https://ase.tufts.edu/cosmos/view_chapter.asp?id=37) ghostly solar neutrinos passing through the tip of your finger, and every other square centimeter of your body, whether you are indoors or outdoors, or whether it is day or night, and without your body noticing them, or them noticing your body. At night they go through the entire Earth before reaching you.

Neutrinos are quantum mechanical elementary particles, and the question, imo, to ask,because quantum mechanics is a probabilistic theory,  "how probable is it for a cosmic neutrino to interact with a nucleus in your cells and create a neutron interaction that will lead to a cancer cell which will develop to cancer"

> [For example the neutrinos](https://cds.cern.ch/record/677618/files/p115.pdf) produced in nuclear reactors with energy E=1MeV have a crosssection of order $10^{-44}$,
> this corresponds to a probability of $10^{-18}$ to interact in a solid detector with the thickness of one meter,

The odds are against the cancer  happening as these numbers show.

Th physics reason this is so , it is because neutrinos are neutral,and interact to first order  with the [weak interaction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_interaction) which means they have a very small probability to interact.

Comment: You only say neutrinos don’t *normally* cause cancer.  OP asked how many you’d actually need.  [Supernovae exceed this amount for a 1AU observer](https://what-if.xkcd.com/73/), ergo OP’s question has an answer.

Comment: @alexchandel [Karam 2002](http://andrewkaram.com/pdf/HPJ.pdf) reminds you the supernova γs will fry you long before that...